# How to place image using SDI application when the dialog first appears?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, sdi

I am developing MFC based SDI application using CFormView class in VC++. My problem is that I need to load image when the dialog initially appears. How to place image in an SDI application..I know for dialog based applications it can be done using OnInitDialog application.But for SDI application there is no such function. I tried placing the image using OnInitialUpdate() and OnPaint() function. But it failed..What should I do to place the image to dialog when it first appears? Please Help

Thanks in advance

Code as I placed in OnInitialUpdate()

```
void CECUSimulatorView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
CFormView::OnInitialUpdate();
GetParentFrame()->RecalcLayout();
ResizeParentToFit();
hBitmap = LoadImage(0,_T("F:/ECUSimulator/ECUSimulator_New/res/LedOff.bmp"),               IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
ImageLoading();
}
```

Code for the function ImageLoading()

```
void CECUSimulatorView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
HDC hDC, hDCToDisplay = NULL;
hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDCToDisplay);
SelectObject(hDC,hBitmap);
hDCToDisplay = ::GetDC(m_picture.m_hWnd);
m_picture.GetWindowRect(&picRect);
BitBlt(hDCToDisplay,0 , 0, (picRect.right - picRect.left), (picRect.bottom -picRect.top), hDC, 0 ,0 ,SRCCOPY);
DeleteDC(hDC);
DeleteDC(hDCToDisplay);
}
```

Here

HANDLE hBitmap;
CStatic m_picture;  //Picture Control
CRect picRect;      //Picture Control Rect

I removed the code from OnInitialUpdate() and placed it in OnPaint() function as follows:

void CECUSimulatorView::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

```
hBitmap = LoadImage(0,_T("F:/ECUSimulator/ECUSimulator_New/res/LedOff.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
ImageLoading();
```

}

Comment: According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1029717/1850797), `OnInitialUpdate()` is the correct place to do GUI-related initialization -- could you show some code as to what is not working?

Comment: I have added my code portions.It is not working please help

Comment: I assume that the second `CECUSimulatorView::OnInitialUpdate()` is actually `CECUSimulatorView::ImageLoading()` -- see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Calling `LoadImage()` in `OnInitialUpdate()` is ok, the actual painting needs to be done in one of the two following ways:

a) in `CECUSimulatorView::OnDraw()` -- easier, but may introduce flickering

b) override the `OnPaint()` function of the `m_picture` control using ClassWizard and draw the picture there

Comment: I followed both steps as above and failed again. Would you please code it using the two methods?

Comment: sorry, I'm not in a position to provide full working solutions -- could you post your painting logic?

Comment: Ok sure.. I used the code inside the OnInitialUpdate() in OnPaint()..i.e the two lines in OnInitialUpdate() function..It is not working..I used the same code in OnDraw() also.It too failed..Am i doing anythng wrong here.?

Comment: When I used that two lines of code in OnPaint() it works when my dialog is moved at runtime with mouse..but not on startup,what i actually needs.

Comment: please post the actual code that you use in `OnInitialUpdate()` and `OnPaint()`

Comment: void CECUSimulatorView::OnPaint()
{
 CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
 // TODO: Add your message handler code here
 // Do not call CFormView::OnPaint() for painting message

 hBitmap = LoadImage(0,_T("F:/ECUSimulator/ECUSimulator_New/res/LedOff.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
 ImageLoading();
 
}

Comment: please read the answer closely -- you need to use either 'OnDraw()' or the **OnPaint() of the control**; also, your `ImageLoading()` needs to use the `DC` from the paint function itself

Comment: How to use the OnPaint() of the control?? I cant find it using class wizard.Please Help

Comment: You will need to derive a new class based on the current class of `m_picture`, you can then handle `WM_PAINT` messages for that control

Comment: Current class means the CStatic class or CFormView class??My project is derived using CFormVIew class and the control derived from CStatic class

Answer (score 0):

[the comments in the previous answer was getting very extended, hence a new answer]

a) derive a new class (say `CMyPicture`) based on CStatic, change `m_picture` to this new class

b) in `CMyPicture`, create a handler for `WM_PAINT`, this will normally be called `CMyPicture::OnPaint()`

c) change your `ImageLoading()` function to take a `CDC *pDC` as parameter and use this `DC` to render the image

d)

```
void CMyStatic::OnPaint(void)
{   CPaintDC dc(this);
    ImageLoading(&dc); // or even move the painting logic here
}
```

NOTE: you can load the image in `OnInitialUpdate()`, no need to load it each time you are painting

An example (for a dialog, but the painting logic should not be affected) in [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7192561/1850797).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my problem.
I used CBitmap class as follows:

CBitmap m_bBitmap1;

In OnInitialUpdate() I wrote as follows :

m_bBitmap1.LoadBitmapW(IDB_BITMAP1);

In OnPaint() I wrote as follows:

m_picture.SetBitmap(m_bBitmap1);

Wherever(In which all functions)need to load image just call the above line of code in corresponding functions..